# Input Parameter Validation in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need a stored procedure to make combination of name and address columns unique.

For example, suppose I have addresses like

```
Address-   12  A, Hilt Road @ Delhi, 201010
Address-   12A:- HILTROAD Delhi, 201010
```

Since both are same except some special characters and spaces. How to validate them during user input with the existing database column? I have two columns - one for complete address and another for Zip code.

Comment: Well, you could replace all the special characters and spaces and then compare the two. However, there is always a chance of misspelling the address (if someone wrote `Hylt road` instead of `Hilt road` you will get "different" addresses)

Comment: Any approach would be highly unreliable, addresses can be written in lots of ways

Comment: Its only a example. Actually I have to compare the user Input address with the existing database address which is huge. That's the task to make this combination unique. Yeah there's lots of ways like special characters, Upper case-lower case, and many more.

Comment: Short answer - use magic because you cannot do this without lots of rules, assumptions, and experience. And any logic you might acquire to do this will never be perfect. There are companies that provide this functionality - go search and discover why this is so difficult.